# How to prevent having to add ip to remotely connect to the database

Tags: database, jdbc, ip, cpanel

In my java program, I connect to a mysql database on my server, but I have to go into my cpanel and add my ip address to be able to remotely access it.
Is there a way to allow all connections or add a mac address instead?

Comment: have you tried `user@'%'` in mysql?

Comment: @Rugal In cpanel, there's a remote mysql option which allows me to add ip addresses. i don't know if user@'%' will work

Comment: just have a try! It is simpler to do this in development!

Comment: @Rugal ok, but what exactly do I do?

Comment: @rason58 just like what you did from `ip`. grant the privilege to user@'%', which `%` means from any where.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rugal, I got it to work.
I used %.%.%.% as the access host to allow any connections and it worked.